# Refresh IFrame with WordPress 3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-3.5

With the previous WordPress version, I used to use the following code to automatically refresh an iframe in a post:

```
<iframe id='feuille1' src="http://competition.hockeyfrance.com/la/ffhgsheet.php?GameID=20094" width="650" height="1000" name='feuille1' ></iframe> 
<script type="text/javascript"> function refreshiframe() { document.getElementById('feuille1').src="http://competition.hockeyfrance.com/la/ffhgsheet.php?GameID=20094" setTimeout("refreshiframe()",30000); } </script> 
<body onload="refreshiframe();">
```

The code is embedded in the post using a shortcode. This worked fine until the recent 3.5 update, which I understand includes an updated version of jQuery.

Can someone help me to understand why this very simple code does not work anymore? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function refreshiframe() {document.getElementById('feuille1').src = "http://competition.hockeyfrance.com/la/ffhgsheet.php?GameID=20094"  setTimeout("refreshiframe()",30000); } </script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function refreshiframe() {document.getElementById('feuille1').src = "http://competition.hockeyfrance.com/la/ffhgsheet.php?GameID=20094"; setTimeout("refreshiframe()",30000); } </script>
```

Notice the `;` dividing the two different js instruction, one for changing the `src` and the other calling the `setTimeout` function.

Good luck!

Comment: That's it! many thanks for your help here. Just missed the typo. Problem resolved.

Comment: Semi-colons can be a pain in the butt! Good luck!